# How to access the epub file from device internal memory?

Tags: android, html, webview, epub

I have created simple android project to load epub files using epub.js. I am rendering epub file using html and javascript in webview control. The required JS, epub and HTML files are placed in Assets folder. Below is my HTML code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head> 
  <script src="file:///android_asset/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Render -->
   <script src="file:///android_asset/epub.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">    
<!--string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); // Documents folder--!>
  var book = ePub("/data/user/0/ShowCaseSample.Droid/files/bookName/");
    $(document).ready(function () { 
   book.renderTo("area");
  });        
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
 <div id="main">
    <div id="prev" onclick="book.prevPage()" style="font-size: 64px;cursor:pointer;" class="arrow">‹</div>
    <div id="area" style="height:500px;"></div>
    <div id="next" onclick="book.nextPage()" style="font-size: 64px;cursor:pointer;" class="arrow">›</div>    
</div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

I have referred the epub file path from Assets folder. It is working fine. But i want to refer the epub file path as device internal memory. When rendering from different location the epub file is not loading. Can anyone suggest me on this?

Comment: Your code in your question does not refer to whatever you consider "Device Special folder location/ download location" to be. It is referring to `file:///android_asset/`. Rather than showing us the code that you are *not* using, edit your question and show us the code that you *are* using. Also, are you seeing any console messages from your JavaScript library show up in LogCat?

Comment: Hi CommonsWare,
I have edited my code with path which i want to refer. The path will be get from android and will pass to html file.